# Is it good and possible to always test an android app on real device rather than using android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to learn android on a dell device having 4gb ram and intel pentium chipset. I am trying to run  hello world app on a emulator but it actually take much time(more than 5 minutes) to start the process and at the end give error message "Error while waiting for device: Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online". As far as testing on device is considered i find it fast and easy.
So my question is that possible to always test an app on real device and skipping the testing on an emulator.
Also suggest me some tips to make my android studio run faster.
.

Comment: it depends on you. Normally virtual device or emulator works slow as compared to other device. Because it uses the system Ram and Rom. Its better to work with external/real time device for testing the code. You have another option for virtual device which is Genymotion.

Comment: will you tell me more about Genymotion and how to use it as virtual device.

Comment: i suggest you to use real time device. Because virtual device will slow your system speed and also it waste a lot of time too while compiling and launching the applications.

Comment: I will always try to use real device first but there will be sometime when it is required to use  emulator for then is it good to use genymotion emulator and also tell me will it work for my device.

Comment: yes it will work. you have to donwload the device which you like to run on your system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its always better to test on a real device. Its very fast especially when debugging. If your emulator is taking long to load imagine a situation where you are trying to debug and want to check the app's behaviour after each change in code. Just install the usb drivers and sdk tool that your device's api version is running on

Answer (score 1):

Sure it is!

First of all, enable the developer mode in your device (if it's not enabled already). Info for doing this [here](http://www.androidcentral.com/how-enable-developer-settings-android-42).

Then just plug your device via USB and it will appear when you run your project in Android Studio.

NOTE: The first time you attempt to run the project, your phone will ask for permissions, make sure you allow it!

Comment: I am done with all this process. help me overcome the error: Error while waiting for device: Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online.

Comment: It seems that you are running against the emulator, nothing to do with running in device. Did you select your device while running the app?

Comment: I have tried to run my hello world app on device(moto e and a lenovo smart phone)  but the font color always appear to black i even tried different font color. would you please recommend me some tips to get rid of that problem. This might be a new question but the forum has banned me for 7 days to ask any question.

Answer (score 0):

It will be good if we are testing the application in real device rather than emulator if you have the device. But we can't buy different density, different dimension, different android version devices for testing so for that purpose we need to use emulator.

To improve the speed of android emulator install HAXM in your system, it will speed up the emulators.

Comment: I have the same thought about the use of emulators. will you help me short out the error: Error while waiting for device: Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online.

Comment: what is the OS version of android device you are trying to start?

Comment: android studio 2.1.2 . I am trying to install and use genymotion as emulator . Is it a good option and will it work for my device(specification mention in initial question also it has 1.7GHz processor).

Comment: oh sorry it is 6.0.

Comment: 6.0 emulators are heavy so try to use device. If want to use emulator then create emulator OS less than 5.0 then try.

Comment: emulator name is "Nexus 5 API23 X86". I can't find any OS version

Comment: you can able to find the API level of OS like 21,22,23

Comment: I have tried to run my hello world app on device(moto e and a lenovo smart phone) but the font color always appear to black i even tried different font color. would you please recommend me some tips to get rid of that problem. This might be a new question but the forum has banned me for 7 days to ask any question.